# JPA cascading merge when it shouldn't

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm having a hard time understanding this JPA behavior which to me doesn't seem to follow the specification.
I have 2 basic entities:

```
public class User {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 36)
  @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
  private ID id;

  @OrderBy("sequence ASC")
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user", cascade = { CascadeType.REMOVE })
  private final Set<UserProfile> userprofiles = new HashSet<UserProfile>(0);

  //Ommiting rest of fields since they aren't relevant
}


public class UserProfile {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 36)
  @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
  private ID id;

  @NotNull
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
  @JoinColumn(name = "userID", nullable = false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_UserProfile_User"))
  private User user;

  //Ommiting rest of fields since they aren't relevant
}
```

As you can see I only have cascading set to REMOVE, the behavior will be the same if I don't have cascade set at all.

Now if I call:

```
User user = new User();
user.setId(UUIDGenerator.generateId());

UserProfile userProfile = new UserProfile();
userProfile.setId(UUIDGenerator.generateId());
userProfile.setUser(user);
user.getUserProfiles().add(userProfile);

em.merge(user);
```

merge will throw an exception.

I see Hibernate is executing a SQL query against the UserProfile table:
select userprofil0_.userProfileID as userProf1_4_0_, userprofil0_.profileID as profileI3_4_0_, userprofil0_.sequence as sequence2_4_0_, userprofil0_.userID as userID4_4_0_ from UserProfile userprofil0_ where userprofil0_.userProfileID=?

And then it will throw an exception
 org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException: Unable to find com.mytest.domain.UserProfile with id 6aaab891-872d-41e6-8362-314601324847;

Why is this query even called?

Since I don't have cascade type set to MERGE in userprofiles my expectation would be that JPA/Hibernate would simply ignore the entities inside userprofiles set and only insert/update the user record, doesn't this go against the JPA specs?

If I change cascadetype to MERGE things will work as expected and both User and UserProfile will be added to the database, so no problem there. What puzzles me is why is Hibernate querying the database and erroring out about an entity that's not supposed to be merged at all since I don't have it set to cascade.

This is more of an academic scenario that I ran into, of course I could simply clear the userprofiles set and things would work, but I'm trying to understand why the above behavior happens since I'm probably missing some crucial piece of information about how merge works. It seems it will always try to attach all entities to the session regardless cascade type being set or not.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is this query even called?

It's because you are trying to merge the entity, in JPA merge() is used to make the entity [managed/attached](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13981/undejbs003.htm#BABIAAGE). To "merge" User, JPA needs to still maintian the references it holds(UserProfile). In your case its not trying to persist `UserProfile` its trying to get a reference to it to merge `User`. Read [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-persist-and-merge/)

If you use persist rather than merge this should not happen.

Comment: Yes, I understand what is trying to do, but is this explained on the JPA specs at all? Because without having CascadeType.MERGE set on User I was expecting it to simply ignore the UserProfile entities when merging. That article is very simple as it doesn't deal with ManyToOne relationships and the behavior explained there is just fine. My doubts are regarding the child records because I can't find anything mentioned about this on JPA or Hibernate specs.